# Error when start Azure Function in Visual Studio Pro 2017

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

when I want to start the Azure Function in 2017 the error comes up:
I don't know why.

```
07.07.2020 20:21:57] Retrying to start listener for function 'Function1' (Attempt 5)
[07.07.2020 20:21:57] A ScriptHost error has occurred
[07.07.2020 20:21:57] The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB: The listener has already been started or is starting.
[07.07.2020 20:21:57] The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB: The listener has already been started or is starting.
[07.07.2020 20:21:57]
[07.07.2020 20:21:57] The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start.
[07.07.2020 20:21:57] The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB: The listener has already been started or is starting.
```

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: maybe to try VS 2019

Comment: Please provided your code herer.

Comment: Can you ensure that the storage emulator is started ? If not, confirming that you are using a general storage account connection string in `local.settings.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Please show the local.settings.json of your function app. Maybe the connection string has some problem.

If your firewall restricts func from accessing the Storage Account, then this error may be reported. The firewall is one of the reasons that the listener cannot access the virtual Storage Emulator.

When running the function locally, all triggers except httptrigger need to use the Storage Emulator. If the firewall restricts the listener's access to virtual storage, problems can occur when performing functions.

Try disabling the firewall and see if that resolves the issue.

**Of course, it is also possible that the Storage Emulator service is not open.** Try typing

```
"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" status
```

in cmd to check the status.

If it returns false, enter the following command to start the Storage Emulator:

```
"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" init
"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" start
```

***To sum up:***

This type of problem is generally for three reasons.

> 1.Connection string error prevents connection,
>
> 2.firewall is set
>
> 3.some services are not turned on.

Please do the above steps and let me know whether you can solve this problem.:)

Comment: @fau2019 Hi, If my answer helps you, can you [mark it as answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsESi.png) to end this question? Thanks.:)